# Thunderbird Can not connect to smtp.googlemail.com

Tags: thunderbird, gmail

I am using Thunderbird ( currently 16.0.2)  for a long time in Ubuntu .
it works perfectly .
But in two weeks , I got a notification: **gmail account exceeded command or bandwidth limits** , and I can not send email as well as receiving email using Thunderbird and iPhone.

I didn't use Mail client ( thunderbird and iphone) for 1 day after that.
And Now , I can read email but can not sending email.

**The message could not be sent because the connection to SMTP server smtp.googlemail.com timed out. Try again or contact your network administrator.**

I try to telnet smtp.googlemail.com port 465 but no luck., port 587 is ok.
I change the the SMTP server to port 587. But I still can not send email.

It show : connected to smtp.googlemail.com , but still show that window , and never send the email.

Any idea ?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to [this](http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha) link after logging into your webmail. and try logging on thunderbird again. i think it should work.

Comment: Hello, thank you. I tried port 587 but can not send email. and I can not telnet to smtp.googlemail.com 465 . Which port you recommend ?

Comment: Thunderbird stuck at "Copying Message to Sent Mail Folder" . and Email was  delivered

Comment: Dont have to change ports man, this happens because when you have many folders and messages in your mail, thundirbird usually check for any updates occasionally. So, google will block the account usually for 24 hours. the link i gave above can make a device trusted. First, login to your mail>go to the link above>Continue. Then try logging in from the thundirbird

Comment: as google quotes, "As a security precaution, Google may prevent an application from accessing your account if it's the first time we've seen this application sign in to your account, or if it's attempting to sign in from a new location"

Answer (score 1):

Try setting 'gmail' instead of 'googlemail', it helped in my case.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue. Thunderbird would receive, but when I tried to send it would time out and not connect to the smtp server. A friend had jacked with the Norton settings and had it set to scan outgoing e-mails. I changed the setting to only scan incoming and it resolved the issue.

Comment: Norton for Ubuntu!?!